# how to filter nested objects based on properties

Tags: javascript

Below is a nested array of objects, how can I filter this based on object property?
ex. if name==="same" then it should return that object

```
const arrNestedObj=[
          {
            "id":"1",
            0:{
              "name":"john",
              "age":"10"
            },
            1:{
              "name":"sam",
              "age":"20"
            }
          },{ 
            "id":"2",
            0:{
              "name":"sam",
              "age":"15"
            },
          }
        ]
```

```
expected output:
if name==="same" then it should return that object
[
  {
    "name":"sam",
    "age":"20"
  },
  {
     "name":"sam",
     "age":"15"
   }
]
```

Comment: Do you need to check if the name is `"sam"` or do you need to check if the same name has been used before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
const output = data.map(i=>Object.values(i).filter(v=>v.name==="sam")).reduce((holder, cur)=>{
    return [...holder,...cur]
},[])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Array.prototype.filter method.

```
const filteredArr = arrNestedObj.filter(elem => elem.name === "sam")
```

Comment: hi thanks, but the name property lies inside the nested object

Answer (score 1):

If your meaning is that you want the name === 'sam' object, then can use `Array.prototype.map()` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`
These two method can help you to get the objects.

***example:***

```html
<script>
const arrNestedObj=[
          {
            "id":"1",
            0:{
              "name":"john",
              "age":"10"
            },
            1:{
              "name":"sam",
              "age":"20"
            }
          },{ 
            "id":"2",
            0:{
              "name":"sam",
              "age":"15"
            },
          }
        ]

let result = [];
arrNestedObj.map((item) => {
  let tempArray = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item)
    for(let i=0; i<tempArray.length-1; i++)
    {
     if(Number(tempArray[i] !== NaN))
     {
       if(item[tempArray[i]].name === "sam")
       {
        result.push(item[tempArray[i]]);
       }
     }
    }
});

console.log(result)
</script>
```